# How to save and show data submitted from texterea editor (tinymce)?

Tags: html, mysql, database, laravel

I am developing a website which contain a post submission. When I save the data from texterea, I noticed that the data is in html format rather than plain text. So, what is the best way to show the data in an article format? I am using tinymce editor.

I'm using laravel, thus I just simply use

```
    auth()->user()->posts()->create([
     'article' => $data['article'],
     ]);
```

To call, I use `{{$data->article}}`. Please noted that, I only specifically show how I save only textera input.

This is my output 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/137jz.png)

This is database 
[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JigdU.png)

This is expected ouput, without html tag.
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dbk7.png)

Comment: pleas show us your input, what you tried and what you expected. Stackoverflow isn't here to write your home work.

Comment: Ajax is a great way to send form without updated the content, so pls edit this question to be more clear about your code

Comment: Sorry for bad question and late reply. I edited the question. Hope can help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{ !! $data->article !! }
```

Blade statements {{   }} are sent to htmlspecialcharacters() to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your html to be escaped you have to use this syntax -> {!!   !!}

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Yes, what happens is that I´m new at stackoverflow and I can´t comment other's posts. I really wanted to comment Sangita´s answer in that way: that his method works but with just one brace

Comment: You don't need to comment anything, simply edit your answer to contain some explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Update: Simply use `<?php echo $post_data->article;?>` will do the job. Can anyone explain the reason?
 [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ecag.png)

Comment: Please do not bypass Laravel's templating engine by this

Comment: @NicoHaase please can i understand why should we not bypass Laravel's templating engine . This is the only working solution to the problem presented here.

Answer (score 0):

You can display html content by many ways in laravel. Here are some examples

Method 1:

```
@php 
   echo $data->article; 
@endphp
```

Method 2:

```
{{ !! $data->article !! }}
```

Method 3:

```
    {{ !! htmlspecialchars_decode($data->article) !! }}
```

OR

```
    {{ !! html_entity_decode($data->article) !! }}
```

Comment: yes sir, I full aware of that. Just the current problem for me is, I have no idea how to make my output for the article to be same like when user key in during submission in html. By simply call `{{$data->article}}` will output it with html tag as in the question. I wonder if I need to process the input before store it in db.

Comment: try using  htmlspecialchars_decode() or html_entity_decode() function. I have updated code please check third method

Comment: using `htmlspecialchars_decode` or `html_entity_decode' not working sir. Still not filter out the html tag.

Comment: use rih text editor like ckeditor or tinymce to show formatted html content

Comment: I am using tinymce editor for this. Html textarea will only produce plain text with `/n` for spacing.